# How to get the elements in a set in C++?

Tags: c++, set, stdset

I am confused as to how to get the elements in the set. I think I have to use the iterator but how do I step through it?

Comment: Both answers below are correct, but to be a bit more direct: Iterators are moved forward or backward through the result set using the increment (++) and decrement (--) operators.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Replace `type` with, for example, `int`.. And `var` with the name of the set

```
for (set<type>::iterator i = var.begin(); i != var.end(); i++) {
   type element = *i;
}
```

The best way though is to use [boost::foreach](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/foreach.html). The code above would simply become:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(type element, var) {
   /* Here you can use var */
}
```

You can also do `#define foreach BOOST_FOREACH` so that you can do this:

```
foreach(type element, var) {
   /* Here you can use var */
}
```

For example:

```
foreach(int i, name_of_set) {
   cout << i;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use iterators:

```
std::set<int> si;
/* ... */
for(std::set<int>::iterator it=si.begin(); it!=si.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
```

Note that many references like MSDN and cplusplus.com provides examples - [one example](http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/begin/). ;)

Answer (score 5):

For C++11 and newer:

```
std::set<int> my_set;
for (auto item : my_set)
    std::cout << item << endl;
```

Answer (score 4):

To list all the elements in the set you can do something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int myints[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  set<int> myset (myints,myints+5);

  set<int>::iterator it;

  cout << "myset contains:";
  for ( it=myset.begin() ; it != myset.end(); it++ )
    cout << " " << *it;

  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

To check if a specific elements in the set or not you can use the find() method from the set STL class

Answer (score 3):

I'm liking what I'm seeing in VS2010 Beta2 using C++0x lambda syntax:

```
std::for_each( s.begin(), s.end(), 
               [](int value)
               { 
                  // what would be in a function operator() goes here.
                  std::cout << value << std::endl; 
               } );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set<int> os;
for (auto itr  = os.begin(); itr != os.end() ; ++itr) cout << *itr << endl;
```